# What is OSError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported for pandas to_csv on colab?

Tags: pandas, export-to-csv

My input is:

```
test=pd.read_csv("/gdrive/My Drive/data-kaggle/sample_submission.csv")
test.head()
```

It ran as expected. 
But, for

```
test.to_csv('submitV1.csv', header=False)
```

**The full error message that I got was:**

```
OSError    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-fde243a009c0> in <module>()
9 from google.colab import files
10 print(test)'''
---> 11 test.to_csv('submitV1.csv', header=False)
12 files.download('/gdrive/My Drive/data- 
kaggle/submission/submitV1.csv')

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in 
to_csv(self, path_or_buf, sep, na_rep, float_format, columns, 
header, index, index_label, mode, encoding, compression, quoting, 
quotechar, line_terminator, chunksize, tupleize_cols, date_format, 
doublequote, escapechar, decimal)
3018                                  doublequote=doublequote,
3019                                  escapechar=escapechar, 
decimal=decimal)
-> 3020         formatter.save()
3021 
3022         if path_or_buf is None:

 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.pyi 
 in save(self)
 155             f, handles = _get_handle(self.path_or_buf, 
 self.mode,
 156                                      encoding=self.encoding,
 --> 157                                      
 compression=self.compression)
 158             close = True
 159 

 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/common.py in 
 _get_handle(path_or_buf, mode, encoding, compression, memory_map, 
 is_text)
 422         elif encoding:
 423             # Python 3 and encoding
 --> 424             f = open(path_or_buf, mode,encoding=encoding, 
 newline="")
 425         elif is_text:
 426             # Python 3 and no explicit encoding

 OSError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported: 'submitV1.csv'
```

Additional Information about the error:
Before running this command, if I run

```
df=pd.DataFrame()
df.to_csv("file.csv")
files.download("file.csv")
```

It is running properly, but the same code is producing the operation not supported error if I try to run it after trying to convert test data frame to a csv file.

I am also getting a message `A Google Drive timeout has occurred (most recently at 13:02:43). More info.` just before running the command.

Answer (score 7):

You are currently in the directory in which you don't have write permissions.

Check your current directory with `pwd`. It might be `gdrive` of some directory inside it, that's why you are unable to save there.

Now change the current working directory to some other directory where you have permissions to write. `cd ~` will work fine. It wil chage the directoy to `/root`. 
Now you can use:

`test.to_csv('submitV1.csv', header=False)`

It will save `'submitV1.csv'` to `/root`